# static libpcap in cross compiled Android arm-v7-a C code

Tags: android, c, arm, cross-compiling, libpcap

I need to build a static library from the latest libpcap and "include" it in a C source code to be cross-compiled for an ARM-v7-a architecture (Nexus One).

I've been trying for days, hope someone could give me an hint.

And I **can't** use neither NDK nor Java-wrapper functions. It needs to be like:

$  -o prog prog.c [-options]
and later I'll be able to push the executable via adb.

I've tried with CodeSourcery and arm-linux-gnueabi installed via apt-get (i'm on Kubuntu Linux), nothing worked properly.

The most I've reached to achieve is a stupid simply helloworld file through:

> arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static -o prog prog.c

which is executed under my smartphone.

Do you have any clue about I can get a more complex program including libpcap? I think it should deal with .a or .so files in libpcap directory but I really don't figure it out...
Thanks in advance

***EDIT - SOLVED***:
Just as auselen said, I've tried with NDK stand-alone toolchain and I've succeded.

This is what I've done, in case somebody would have my same issues:

1) Download Android SDK and NDK (the latter is at r8d version at this time)

2) Go into NDK folder and type

> cd build/tools
>
> make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-3 --install-dir=$HOME/new_toolchain --ndk-dir=YOUR_NDK_PATH
>
> cd $HOME/new_toolchain

(I've put my helloworld.c file in this folder but of course you can add PATH into your .bashrc file for more efficiency)

> bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld

3)push it into your device through adb.

All is working now :) thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Android uses a different runtime (bionic) it is still best to use NDK which has the necessary components to link your application accordingly.

NDK allows you to run it as a [standalone toolchain](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html), so you can directly initiate `gcc` via its `sysroot` feature.

An important tip is to not use `~` in those paths specified when invoking `gcc`, it isn't that friendly.

Comment: Thanks auselen for your answer. Unfortunately my project must deal with a direct and single console command for cross-compiling phase.
In particular I've managed cross-compiling a little traffic sniffer using libpcap with this command:
>arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o prog -static -Llib prog.c -Ilibpcap-1.2.1/ -lpcap

using the given libpcap.a static library.

Comment: @Rob013 I saw this point of yours in a few places about single command. Thing I don't understand is, you can use NDK in another environment with a single command, that's possible and what I mean by standalone toolchain.